# BibTeX: same author, different years

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

Citing `\cite{paper1,paper2,paper3}`, with the `apalike` style, some papers of a same author gives me something like

> [LastName, 2001, LastName, 2002, LastName, 2003]

I would prefer something like this:

> [LastName, 2001, 2002, 2003]

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Please, include here the corresponding entries from your `.bib` file. I may have the solution, but I have to know, if it is relevant in your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The citation format you want is already defined in `apalike`, unless you modified the style. Try the following and if it does not help, maybe update your `natbib` package.

In `mybib.bib` I have three entries from different years, where the first two have the same authors and the third is modified:

```
@article{jd12,
  author={Doe, J. and Bar, F. and Smith, J.},
  title={Some title 1},
  journal={Some journal},
  year={2012},
}

@article{jd13,
  author={Doe, J. and Bar, F. and Smith, J.},
  title={Some title 2},
  journal={Some journal},
  year={2013},
}

@article{jd14,
  author={Doe, J. and Simpson, H. and Bar, F.},
  title={Some title 3},
  journal={Some journal},
  year={2014},
}
```

Now for the main document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Cite the first pair normally \cite{jd12,jd13}, then the second pair in text \citet{jd13,jd14} and now the first and the third in brackets \citep{jd12,jd14}.

We can also cite them all at once, e.~g. in brackets \citep{jd12,jd13,jd14}, or switch them \citet{jd14,jd12,jd13}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{mybib}{}

\end{document}
```

Which will give this as output:

[image: text]
[image: bib]

**EDIT from Ansa211:**

You can even define custom commands that make use of the merged list of authors; for example, if you often find yourself writing `\citeauthor{X}'s \citeyearpar{X}`, you can add this to your preamble:

[image: citehis]

Comment: Works perfectly. To get exactly the same format than before, I used `\usepackage[square]{natbib}` and changed `\cite{}` to `\citep{}`. Thank you!

Comment: It also works with \bibliographystyle{apa}.