# Compact citation for several papers of the same author

Tags: biblatex, natbib

When I cite several Papers by the same (or similar) author(s) (e.g. Doe *et al.*) I obtain an output like

> Doe *et al.* (1999), Doe *et al.* (2002), Doe *et al.* (2004)

However, I would prefer a compact output like

> Doe *et al.* (1999, 2002, 2004)

How do I achive this behavior using biblatex? 
I am aware of the according answer for [bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204352/bibtex-same-author-different-years) but do not see how this should be adapted for biblatex.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[natbib = true,
    style = authoryear,
    backend = biber,
    hyperref = true,
    giveninits = true, 
    maxbibnames = 8, maxcitenames = 2, 
    uniquename=false,         
    uniquelist = minyear,
    doi = false, url = false, isbn = false, eprint = false]
    {biblatex} %
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
    some text about \citet{Doe1999, Doe2002, Doe2004}, but the output should be Doe et al. (1999, 2002, 2004)

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the bibliography:

```
@Article{Doe2002,
  author  = {John Doe and Albert Miller and Jack Frost and Gregor Smith},
  title   = {Paper 2},
  journal = {Journal of Best Research},
  year    = {2002},
}

@Article{Doe2004,
  author  = {John Doe and Jack Frost and Albert Miller},
  title   = {Paper 3},
  journal = {Journal of Cool Research},
  year    = {2004},
}

@Article{Doe1999,
  author  = {John Doe and Albert Miller and Jack Frost},
  title   = {Paper 1},
  journal = {Journal of New Research},
  year    = {1999},
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the style `authoryear-comp` instead of `authoryear`.