# Remove comma behind author for textcite only

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I have recently moved from the `authoryear` style to `authoryear-comp` ([reason](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366190/compact-citation-for-several-papers-of-the-same-author)). However now commas appear behind the the authorlist regardless of  whether `\citet` or `\citep` are used:

> (Doe etal., 2002) for `\citep` and Doe etal., (2002)  for `\citet`

For the latter this is wanted, for the former it just look ugly.
How do I get rid of that comma? 
I know that I can redefine `nameyeardelim` but that removes the comma for both cases.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[natbib = true,
    style = authoryear-comp,
    backend = biber,      
    hyperref = true,   
    giveninits = true,
    maxbibnames = 8, maxcitenames = 2,
    uniquename=false,
    uniquelist = minyear,
    doi = false, url = false, isbn = false, eprint = false]
    {biblatex} %
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
    some text about \citet{Doe1999, Doe2002, Doe2004}, where \citet{Doe1999} are referenced and others \citep{Doe2002}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

bibliography:

```
@Article{Doe2002,
  author  = {John Doe and Albert Miller and Jack Frost and Gregor Smith},
  title   = {Paper 2},
  journal = {Journal of Best Research},
  year    = {2002},
}

@Article{Doe2004,
  author  = {John Doe and Jack Frost and Albert Miller},
  title   = {Paper 3},
  journal = {Journal of Cool Research},
  year    = {2004},
}

@Article{Doe1999,
  author  = {John Doe and Albert Miller and Jack Frost},
  title   = {Paper 1},
  journal = {Journal of New Research},
  year    = {1999},
}
```

Desired output would look like the following

- `\citep`: (Doe etal., 2002)
- `\citet`: Doe etal. (2002)

Comment: I get no comma with \citet. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer probably not. I run a TeXlive install from June 2016 and biblatex seems to be version 3.4. I had hoped not to  reinstall TeXlive three days before handing in a 200 page document ;)

Comment: Texlive has a backup system. So it should be quite safe to update only biblatex and biber (`tlmgr update biblatex`) and to try out if something explodes. You could store your current biblatex-folder  and biber.exe is some safe place first. Or install texlive 2017 pretest beside your texlive 2016: changing between both systems is easy.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks, that was the problem. TL2017 also seems to run fine :)