# Making author names bold in references

Tags: bibliographies

How can I make author names bold in references with "apalike" bib style?
To be more clear, how can I make author names bold in the following example:
[BibTeX: same author, different years](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204352/bibtex-same-author-different-years)

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex-apa`?

Comment: Could you give more details please? biblatex-apa is a package?

Comment: Yes. It defines an `apa` style for biblatex. The main point is that `biblatex` is easier to customise than `bibtex`. Furthermore, the bibliography engine, by default, is `biber`, which understands `utf8`

Comment: Could you reference some links?

Comment: What do you mean? Reference an url? Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Do you have any concrete idea to make the author names bold in this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204352/bibtex-same-author-different-years

Comment: Probably patching the relevant command with `\mkbibbold`  via `xpatch`. It's hard to say more without a concrete example